# Pass authenticated User to REST endpoint

Tags: rest, asp.net-core-mvc, httpcontext

I have a REST API application which is getting the information about the logged in user from HttpContext.

On the other side I have an ASP.NET Core MVC application which provides the user authentication.

How do I call the first application's endpoint and pass the information about the logged in user?

Comment: Are you looking for  `RequestContext.Principal` inside a method on APIController?

Comment: Um, no. Sorry, I mislabeled the question. What I'm using is `AspNetCore.Mvc`, not `AspNet`. Fixed the tags already.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're dealing with two differing authentication schemes. A traditional website (your ASP.NET Core MVC app) uses cookie authentication. Upon successful login, the server sets a cookie. On each subsequent request, the browser sends this cookie back to the server, essentially authorizing the request.

An API is slightly different. First, they typically don't utilize cookies. Second, since you're typically making requests via a thin client (AJAX, `HttpClient`, etc.) nothing happens automatically. Whereas a web browser is programmed to do this cookie shuffling stuff so the user doesn't need to think about it, if you fail to send something along with the request to an API to authorize it, it's simply not authorized.

The typical approach to authorization via an API is an authentication token. The client will first hit an endpoint on the API to authenticate, where some form of credentials will have to be passed in the request body. The API then responds with an authentication token. Then, the client can proceed to request other protected endpoints via including this token in an `Authorization` request header.

Long and short, if you just go to some website in your browser and login, that doesn't mean you're now logged in for the purposes of an API, even if you're actually making requests to that API in the same browser.

While it's possible to set up a single app to provide multiple means of authentication, it requires some work, and you'll have to make decisions about how exactly you want to handle authentication/authorization and figure out how to effectively implement it.

Personally, I'd recommend just using IdentityServer. It can tie into your existing Identity setup, but gives you virtually everything you could possibly need right out of the box. You can do token auth, JWTs, or even OAuth workflows. It's free as in beer and open source, as well.

Comment: Can you provide some example how to do it using IdentityServer? I believe I have all the information I need in a property (of type System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal) `Controller.User` but I can't figure out how can I use them in my call to the REST endpoint.